# How to add onClick event on the options in Autocomplete Component(Material UI)?

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

How is possible to add onClick event on the options - i mean when u click the selected option i want to link somewhere, not to just put in the searchField(or textField)? I search really hard on the web, but i just cant find how to do that.

```
            <Autocomplete
              freeSolo
              classes={classes}
              options={searchItems}
              getOptionLabel={(option) =>
                option.title ? option.title : option.name
              }
              style={{ width: 300, borderRight: "none", borderLeft: "none" }}
              renderInput={(params) => {
                return (
                  <TextField
                    {...params}
                    variant="outlined"
                    fullWidth
                    placeholder="Search for movie, tv or person"
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the onChange function inside the `Autocomplete` component as below:

```
<Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      classes={classes}
      options={searchItems}
      getOptionLabel={(option) =>
            option.title ? option.title : option.name
          }
      style={{ width: 300, borderRight: "none", borderLeft: "none" }}
      onChange={(e, value) => console.log(e.target, value.title)}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
```

[Here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-udt10?file=/demo.js:233-563) that I have created. When the `onChange` function in the `Autocomplete` component is triggered, it displays values on the console. According to the doc, onchange function here pass three props called `event`, `value` and `reason`.

Comment: Note that it doesn't fire if you wanna click the same item again afterwards. Only when selected item actually changed.

Answer (score 0):

Autocomplete does't provide `onClick` callback . The only and  simple way is wrap the Autocomplete with Box component.

```js
   <Box
        onClick={() => {
          console.log('clicked');
        }}>
        <Autocomplete
          id={id}
```